# JavaScript .scroll function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have been trying for hours now but couldn't find a reason why the following code is not working on my site (http://robo.im) -

```
    <script>
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400) { 
            $('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0.98);
        }
        else{
            $('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

I'm calling it in the footer with 'script' tags and have included all the necessary files. Kindly help and take a look into the page source if required.

Comment: Did you place it inside the `$(document).ready`?

Comment: @Robo see the above comment by osi.

Comment: I didn't get that @osi, totally new to Javascript.

Comment: You should probably lead with the fact that you're using Wordpress, then someone would have pointed you to the codex, which specifically states that jQuery is in no-conflict mode in Wordpress.

Comment: @osi - why, your answer is wrong ?

Comment: I have no clue? Looks like someone is trolling around.

Comment: There's no need for document.ready, the window is always available, it doesn't have to wait for the document to load. The issue is that Wordpress does not use $, it uses jQuery as it's in no-conflict mode by default -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: @adeneo Since you did not posted an answer, I have updated my example referring to your url.

Comment: @osi - no problem, answer away!

Comment: I had issues with window scroll and it turned out to be a css issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you put your script code within the `$(document).ready`. This functions makes sure the complete page content has been loaded. Otherwise you could apply functions to elements which do not exist.

So in your example you are binding the `scroll` function while the document has not been completed loaded yet.

Also make sure you have loaded jQuery correctly. @adeneo pointed correctly that Wordpress uses `jQuery` instead of `$` as the reference to jQuery.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400) { 
            $('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0.98);
        }
        else{
            $('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at your page, and it appears that jQuery is not bound to the $ variable. Either you have some script that is calling [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) (this may be in a library that you have added or in your own code) or there is something overwriting $.

I would suggest either fixing that issue, or changing all $ in your code to jQuery instead:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 400) { 
        jQuery('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0.98);
    }
    else{
        jQuery('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if you are sure this will not cause problems, you can do this just before your existing code:

```
$ = jQuery;
```

Finally, as advised in another answer, it would be best to wrap your entire code block in a $(document).ready or similar. A working snippet would be:

```
$ = jQuery;
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400) { 
            $('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0.98);
        } else{
            $('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0);
        }
    });
});
```

However, I tried this on your site, and whatever is `.home #masthead` has no content, so you won't actually see it doing anything.

Comment: This is just wrong, if the CMS doesn't map $, neither should you, you should use a closure that sets a scope where $ is defined, not assign a global.